# Why do I need to update strokeDashoffset after updating strokeDasharray?

Tags: javascript, svg

In the following, I create a red circle that is drawn only part way around the edge. If I set `strokeDasharray` to `500 628`, which should be the dash length and dash offset, I get the partial circle I am looking for. However, I cannot, afterwards, just set `strokeDasharray = "600"` afterwards to only set the dash length. I **must** include the dash offset as previous `strokeDasharray = "600 628"`.

Why can't I change the dash length by itself?

The actual code is this line: `el.style.strokeDasharray="500 628";`

I would just like to change it by doing this: `el.style.strokeDasharray="200";`

```js
    var el=document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
    el.style.strokeDasharray="500 628";
```

```css
svg {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background: #eee;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
svg #shape {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle id='shape' cx='120' cy='120' r='100' />
</svg>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't seem to reproduce this issue in Firefox or Chrome latest: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/BaaYYGm

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Chrome. Both Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu for me.

Comment: That's quite strange! I'm running them under Windows, but I would actually be surprised if that had an influence on the SVG rendering engine.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I made an edit to show how I'm trying to change the line length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the 2nd value you are passing is not the strokeDashoffset. It is a 2nd length value.

According to [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty):

> A list of comma and/or white space separated lengths (which can have a unit identifier) and percentages. A percentage represents a distance as a percentage of the current viewport. A negative value is an error. If the sum of the values is zero, then the stroke is rendered as if a value of none were specified.

You can see in this example that it is different:

```css
svg {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background: #eee;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
svg #shape1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 600 100;
}
svg #shape2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 600;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle id='shape1' cx='120' cy='120' r='100' />
</svg>
<svg>
  <circle id='shape2' cx='120' cy='120' r='100' />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is correct and I mis-understood the article I read. The article defined the second value as a "dash gap" and, later, said it was offsetting the dash which confused the issue in their coding and writing.